# Javascript countdown + price adjustment

Tags: php, javascript, countdown

I was trying to make a JS countdown script that adjusts both the seconds to go and the price that has to be paid.

For example:
You will be redirected in **5** seconds or click here to pay **150** to redirect immediately.

So, 30 virtual coins a second.

I have already tried to make it but I suck at JS.

So, what I tried (by copy/pasting other codes found on the internet):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    if(secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        location.href='mywebpage.php';
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);

        timeout = 4;
        if(document.getElementById('costs'))
            document.getElementById('costs').innerHTML='&euro; '+(timeout*30);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = formatTime (timeout);
        timeout--;
}
</script>
```

Then offcourse having the HTML:

```
<div id="costs"></div>
<div id="status"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">countDown(3000,"status");</script>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Auto count down, has to redirect when the counter hits zero, has to take off 30 something every second from the second "counter".

All tips will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Note that the countdown works, timeout also works but I don't know how to link the countdown to the timeout = 4 (the number of the countdown function should be at 4, already tried document.getElementById('status'); and stuff like that).

Edit 2:

Fixed!

So, figured it out.

For the people that are also searching for a similar JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown(secs, ele)
{

    if(secs <= -1)
    {
        location.href = 'rangtest.php'; // No need to kill a timeout it only fires once
    }
    else
    {
        // This is just copying your code, you should fix this to use the targeted ele
        if(document.getElementById('costs'))
            document.getElementById('costs').innerHTML='&euro; '+(secs*30);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = (secs);

        secs--;
        setTimeout( function() { countDown(secs, ele); }, 1000);
    }
}

</script>
```

Thanks to @Dan Mayor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always had problems trying to apply arguments to the timer functions which have led me to always define an anonymous function that in turn calls what I am trying to call.  Below will need some modification but should help.

```
function countDown(secs, ele)
{
    if(secs <= 0)
    {
        location.href = 'mypage.htm'; // No need to kill a timeout it only fires once
    }
    else
    {
        // This is just copying your code, you should fix this to use the targeted ele
        if(document.getElementById('costs'))
            document.getElementById('costs').innerHTML='&euro; '+(secs*30);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = formatTime (secs);

        secs--;
        setTimeout( function() { countDown(secs, ele); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your console for more information.  In my example I used "ele" instead of "elem" for the second argument name.  If you copy and pasted you are probably failing on element.innerHTML.  Because elem doesn't exist a call to var element = document.getElementById(elem) would return "unidentified" or null.

Comment: Noticed, still can't figure this one out. Probably too inexperienced with JS, haha. Anyways, thanks for your help so far, but could you explain a little more? As like how to actually make it work?

Comment: What does your browser console say?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: formatTime is not defined rangtest.php:15
countDown rangtest.php:15
(anonymous function)

Also, the following code:
<script type="text/javascript">countDown(10,"status");</script>  
sets the "virtual cash" to 300, which is good, but the timer doesnt work.

Comment: If formatTime is causing an error prior to the timer there's your culprit.  Timer's are a bit confusing when you try to call by name but when you use the anonymous function wrapper they get very easy.  Many browsers fail hard on uncaught exceptions (meaning they terminate on the spot).  Look in to all of your errors, fix whatever you can first.  Without seeing all of the code in action I can't say for sure but at a glance it sounds like other issues are terminating your script before the timer even starts to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use jquery's bind function instead of paying the overhead of creating a new anonymous function every time:

```
setTimeout(countDown.bind(this, secs, ele), 1000);
```